# Commands out of sync with first request

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I fix this?  The following code returns: `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`
I intentionally opened the connection within the object so I did not need to worry about possible unresolved requests.  and to make things stranger the file calling this does nothing with the sql server before calling this.

Only thing I can think of that may possibly be the problem is the calling file is an ajax call.

```
<?php
require_once "includes/config.php";
require_once "includes/security_ajax.php";

class Cost {
    public static function price($id,$priceRule='!!!') {
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATA);
        if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

        //get model info
        $query="SELECT `shop`,`modelVolume`,`buildVolume`,`mass`,`salesRule` FROM `models` WHERE `id`=?";
        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
        $stmt->bind_result($shop,$modelVolume,$buildVolume,$mass,$salesRule);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $stmt->error;die();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a good sleep found the answer.  `$stmt->execute();` needs to be executed before `$stmt->fetch();`  Didn't even look for this since normally when I see this error it is do to another request being executed without being closed.